# In search of California ecosystem vegetation field guide

Tags: ecology, resources, vegetation, california

I am searching for an illustrated naturalist handbook to coastal California vegetation (trees, shrubs, wildflowers) organized by ecosystem.

For example, there might be sections for coastal dunes (with illustrations and information for beach sagewort, mock Heather, beach primrose, etc), chaparral (chamise, toyon, manzanita, sticky monkey, etc), coastal sage scrub (California sagebrush, coyote brush, sticky monkey), oak woodland, Monterey pine forest, and so forth.

Color illustrations would be ideal for easier identification.

Does anyone know of a book or set of books/guides that could provide this overview, or at least get close? I would also settle for separate sources of the tree/shrub/flower illustrations and the details of common species by ecosystem.

There's often great local signage at state parks providing this sort of information, but I have not been able to locate a comparable reference guide.

Many thanks!